# How to use ReplaceRows from .NET Google.Apis.Fusiontables.v2 (stream csv)?

Tags: google-maps, google-fusion-tables, google-api-dotnet-client

Goal: to update a Fusion Table by replacing old rows by new ones from a csv file without headers using ReplaceRows().

I am using the Google.Apis.Fusiontables.v2 library.

I have read and reread the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/fusiontables/v2/csharp/latest/annotated.html), but still can`t get my code working.

Authentication is working and I am able to perform simple INSERTs without issue:

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO 11t9VLt3vzb46oGQMaS2LTSPWUyBYNcfi1shkmvag (rpu_id, NO_BAIL, 'Usage (description)', 'Use (description)', 'Sup. louable m2', 'Sup. Utilisable m2', 'SumTotal Lou', 'Percent Lou', 'SumTotal Util', 'Percent Util') VALUES (9999,1111,'Test','Test En',1,2,3,4,5,6)"
Sqlresponse sqlRspnse = service.Query.Sql(sql).Execute();
```

I have tried `ReplaceRowsMediaUpload` and `ReplaceRowsMediaUpload` directly from the TableResource class without luck.

Calling the upload function from the service object doesn't error out, but I'm not sure what to do next that would actually replace the rows in the Fusion Table (service is a FusiontablesService):

```
StreamReader str = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("~") + @"\sample2.csv");
service.Table.ReplaceRows("1X7JMLFy75uq20UnU6cLrGTTDfp6lLuD1Fc3vYYjQ", str.BaseStream, "text/csv").Upload();
```

I've tried:

```
service.Table.ReplaceRows("1X7JMLFy75uq20UnU6cLrGTTDfp6lLuD1Fc3vYYjQ").Execute()
```

following the upload, but this just puts the Fusion table in "stuck" mode.

Can someone please provide the lines required to make ReplaceRows work? (Explanations would be appreciated, but aren't necessary!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change "text/csv" for "application/octet-stream". (See accepted MIME type here: https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v2/reference/table/replaceRows)

```
StreamReader str = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("~") + @"\sample2.csv");
service.Table.ReplaceRows("1X7JMLFy75uq20UnU6cLrGTTDfp6lLuD1Fc3vYYjQ", str.BaseStream, "application/octet-stream").Upload();
```

The call to Upload should be enough.

Also, try to create a new table to test it out, to be sure it is setup correctly.

Comment: Of note that ReplaceRows only accepts "application/octet-stream" streams, so I believed that the this parm was referring to the actual contents of the stream.

Also for pointing out is that for unknown reasons, some copies of Fusion Tables will not accept ReplaceRows. Creating an identical table from scratch seems to always work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a REST API call to replace a row in your Google Fusion table directly instead of writing methods to do that. Here is an example:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/fusiontables/v2/tables/tableId/replace
```

Please refer to [this](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v2/reference/table/replaceRows) document for more details, it has a testing environment tool too.

Comment: The Google.Apis.Fusiontables.v2 is a library created be Google for .NET applications. I am looking for the way to use the existing calls within c#.